# Faddeev-Popov ghost propagator in canonical quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, fermions, yang-mills, ghosts

Obtaining the propagator for the [Faddeev-Popov (FP) ghosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev-Popov_ghosts) from the path integral language is straightforward. It is simply

$$\langle T(c(x) \bar c(y))\rangle~=~\int\frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i e^{-ip.(x-y)}}{p^2-\xi m^2+i\epsilon}.$$

But I am unable to properly derive it following canonical quantization route.

The problem is that for anti-commuting fields, the time-ordered product is defined as

$$\langle T(c(x) \bar c(y))\rangle=\theta(x^0-y^0)\langle c(x) \bar c(y)\rangle-\theta(y^0-x^0)\langle \bar c(y)  c(x)\rangle$$

with a *minus* sign between the two terms.  This minus sign is preventing me from closing the contours in the correct way to obtain the expression in my first equation.

The only way I can save this is to say that FP ghosts are special, and their time-ordered product is defined with a plus sign instead of the minus sign.  Is this legitimate?  What is the right way to get the Ghost propagator following canonical quantization route?

Comment: 1. What is $\xi$? If it is $\pm 1$ metric convention, it also affects the $i\epsilon$ term. 2. Have you added an overall phase to $Z[j]$ to absorb the $i$ factor in the kinetic term of the ghost field? 3. Could you write the relevant action/hamiltonian, the Heisenberg picture ghost fields as a function of creation/anhilation operators and the anticommutation relations to see your conventions?

Comment: By the way, is that a book problem or something you are thinking about? Because I would guess that the questions doesn't make sense. I think that the canonical formalism does not follow directly from the path integral version in FP trick. The closest could be BRST quantization, but there $c$ and $\bar c$ are independent real fields (so the your propagator is 0). I think that in a noncovariant formalism like the canonical makes more sense to fix the temporal gauge instead a covariant one.

Comment: Last question: how do you deduce the $i\epsilon$ terms from the path integral if you don't know the vacuum wave functional? Or you know it?

Comment: Another issue: The Hamiltonian for a scalar fermionic field is not bounded from bellow.

Comment: @drake In the propagator, $\xi$ is the gauge parameter, which comes by adding $\frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial.A)^2$ to the Lagrangian in the BRST approach.  I am trying to understand covariant canonical quantization (in the BRST language, of course) so that I may ultimately be able to discuss single-particle states and carry out the LHZ reduction formula for scattering amplitudes.  Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: Oh... I though you were working out the simpler case without Higgs mechanism (then $m=0$ in your propagator). OK, I'm reading your answer bellow...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution to this problem comes from the sneaky fact [(Kugo, 1978)](http://ptp.ipap.jp/link?PTP/60/1869) that while the FP ghost field is hermitian $c^\dagger (x) = c(x)$, the anti-ghost field is *anti*-hermitian $\bar c^\dagger (x)=-\bar c (x)$ .

As a result, the plane wave expansion for the ghost/anti-ghost fields [(Becchi, 2008), Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Becchi-Rouet-Stora-Tyutin_symmetry) are:

$$ c^a(x)={1 \over(2 \pi)^{3/2}} \int_{k_0= | \vec k|}  {d \vec k \over 2 k_0}( \gamma^a( \vec k)e^{-ik \cdot x}+ (\gamma^a)^\dagger( \vec k)e^{ik \cdot x})$$
$$\bar c^a(x)={1 \over(2 \pi)^{3/2}} \int_{k_0= | \vec k|}  {d \vec k \over 2 k_0}( \bar \gamma^a( \vec k)e^{-ik \cdot x}- (\bar\gamma^a)^\dagger( \vec k)e^{ik \cdot x}) \ ,
$$
with a *minus* sign between the two terms in mode expansion for the anti-ghost field.

Thus, when evaluating the time ordered correlator (propagator), the minus sign in the plane-wave expansion compensates the minus sign in the definition of the time-ordering shown in my question above.  Thus, I am able to derive the standard Feynman propagator for the FP ghost field.

Comment: Interesting. Weinberg however defines both fields as hermitians in the 2nd volume of his QFT book. I guess he introduces an $i$ factor that makes it real. And this has to make to do with the $i$ in the kinetic term that sometimes is reabsorbed in a redefinition of $Z[j]$. I also think that the minus sign in $\bar c$ makes the Hamiltonian bounded from bellow. What I'm wondering is what happen with the hermiticity of the hamiltonian. Good question and answer!

Comment: It would be nice if you complete your answer with the full free canonical quantization  if you already have everything clear. Essentially: commutation relations between ghost fields, non interacting ghost Hamiltonian in Fock space and vacuum wave functional.

Comment: By the way, it is obvious from the Heisenberg fields that the Hamiltonian must be $H=\sum_a \int d^3\mathbf{K}~\left(\bar\gamma_\mathbf{K}^{a~\dagger}\gamma_\mathbf{K}^a+\gamma_\mathbf{K}^{a~\dagger}\bar\gamma_\mathbf{K}^a-\text{vacuum energy}\right)$ I asked for an explicit calculation, besides the anticommutation realations and the vacuum wave function.

Comment: @QuantumDot the link to [Kubo, 1978] seems to be dead. Is it only me? In any case, an alternative link is https://academic.oup.com/ptp/article/60/6/1869/1846386/

Comment: This is a very nice answer that was helpful for me. One possible useful point for others: the ghost term in the Lagrangian is $\partial_\mu \bar{c}\partial^\mu c$.  In order for the Lagrangian to be real (i.e. $\mathcal{L}^\dagger=\mathcal{L}$), one sees that either $c$ or $\bar{c}$ must be anti-Hermitian.