# $U(1)$ Faddeev-Popov formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, gauge-theory, path-integral, ghosts

What is the correct series expansion for the $U(1)$ Faddeev-Popov ghosts?

*I know that the $U(1)$ ghosts are only a phase such that they can be neglected in most cases but it turns out that this is not true in curved spaces even for $U(1)$ theories so please don't answer this...*

In this thread [Faddeev-Popov ghost propagator in canonical quantization](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44250/) I found that $c$ is hermitian and $\bar{c}$ anti-hermitian which makes sense since $\bar{c} = c^\dagger \gamma_0$.

But in the $U(1)$ case the ghost are Grassmann variables such that $\bar{c} = c^\dagger \gamma_0$ doesn't make sense does it?

---

For those willing to help me even more. I think that the source of my problem is a poor understanding of the Faddeev-Popov mechanism. More precisely, what happens when $\det(\square)$ is written as a path integral? What exactly do the $c$ and $\bar{c}$ fields mean? Why is it said that one is a ghost and the other an anti ghost?

When quantizing them I obtain $\{ c_k , \bar{c_{k'}}\} = -\delta(k-k')$ how does this tell us anything regarding the norm of these ghosts?

I read Peskin and Schroeder but they do not answer this question (or I missed it).

*Finally, my sincere aplogies for this "all over the place" type question. I fail to pinpoint the exact sources of my confusion that's why my question is rather broad. I hope that someone more experiences can pinpoint it with the above information.*

Comment: What do you mean by "what happens" when the functional determinant is written as a path integral?

Comment: In general, what are the c and $\bar{c}$ fields ? 
Are they related or not ?
I read that one is hermitian and one anti-hermitian and why ?
What is the canonical commutation relation for these fields ?

Comment: The claim $\overline{c}=c^\dagger\gamma_0$ is wrong, because it relates the antighost to the ghost, and these are completely different fields (the prefix anti- and the bar above $c$ don't have their usual meanings in this context).

Comment: @J.G. 
Great I was already suspecting this. How does one than explain that $\bar{c}$ is antihermitian and c hermitian ?

Comment: @gertian That's only one convention. Kugo and Ojima 1979 is another important paper on the FP term, and scales so both fields are Hermitian. This requires an $i$ factor so the Lagrangian is Hermitian.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for telling me both authors of that paper. I had been looking for it but could not find it...
So it really is a definition such, in the end, the Lagrangian is real. I shouldn't search for more meaning ? 
Thanks for your help I understand it now (I think) people have strange notations don't they...

Comment: The paper: http://ci.nii.ac.jp/els/110001875569.pdf?id=ART0002049627&type=pdf&lang=en&host=cinii&order_no=&ppv_type=&lang_sw=&no=1491841369&cp=

Comment: Thank you very much.
If you compile these answers in a post I'll accept it. 
(no need to do so I have what I needed but if you want the reputation that you earned...)

Comment: @J.G. that's true, but it isn't the first wrong thing with the claim which meets the eye. Ghosts are scalars! What $\gamma_0$?

Comment: Indeed that is what I meant with "$\gamma_a c^\dagger$ doesn't make sence"
The answer is this c and $\bar{c}$ are unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in [Kugo and Ojima 1979](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/els/110001875569.pdf?id=ART0002049627&type=pdf&lang=en&host=cinii&order_no=&ppv_type=&lang_sw=&no=1491841369&cp=), "ghost is Hermitian, anti-ghost is anti-Hermitian" is just a convention, another being that both fields are Hermitian, which results in a factor of $i$ in the FP-ghost term so that the Lagrangian is still Hermitian. In their notation $c,\,\overline{c}$ are both Hermitian while $C:=c,\,\overline{C}:=i\overline{c}$ provide a half-Hermitian convention. Then $$\mathcal{L}_{FP}=-i\partial_\mu\overline{c}D^\mu c=-\partial_\mu\overline{C}D^\mu C.$$